# Newby segmentation fault in cs50 pset 5

Tags: c, memory, cs50

I am currently working on pset5 of cs50 and I seem to have an issue allocating memory. Valgrind is telling me that I have an error on line 90, giving me the error;

> invalid read of size 8  at (hex value): load (dictionary.c:90)
>
> //I amcorrect in assuming this line says my problem occurs around line 90, I hope.
>
> at (hex value): main (speller.c40)
>
> //this line (if it is line 40) is 'bool loaded = load(dictionary);', calls my (probably faulty) load function.
>
> address (hex value) is not stack'd,
> malloc'd or (recently) free'd.

I haven't malloc'd my hash table as I thought defining it would do that for me. Trying (with a beginners understanding) to malloc returns errors. Perhaps I have not assigned enough space, but I changed the size of the table to a million, with N, and still got the same error.
(The big N is my attempt at minimizing the allocated space, but I failed math hard so ignore that part if it's wrong, I'll set it back to a higher value for testing)

This code is meant to be run in another algorithm provided by cs50. With this error being unique to me, it seems safe to assume the problem is with my code and not the code written by a Harvard professor, but I can provide that code if needed.

Here is the function that I believe is the problem.

```
// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // open dict file and check if successful
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if(file == NULL){
    return false;
    }

    //take words from file.
    char word[LENGTH+1];
    while(fscanf(file, "%s", word) != EOF){


        //make new temporary node to store data for words
        node *temp_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if(temp_node == NULL){
            return false;
        }
        //transfer word into temporary node
        memset(temp_node->word, '\0', sizeof(temp_node->word));
        strcpy(temp_node->word, word);
        //set pointer to next node to NULL to prepare for future steps
        temp_node->next = NULL;


        //place temp node into table
        location = hash(temp_node->word);
        if(table[location] == NULL){
            table[location] = temp_node;
            counter = counter + 1;
        }
        else{
            table[location]->next = temp_node;
        }
        fclose(file);
    }
        return true;

}
```

here is the entire code, if that helps.

```
// Implements a dictionary's functionality
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "dictionary.h"


// TODO: Choose number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = (104 * LENGTH)+1;


int location = 0;
int key;
int i;
int word2;
char a[N];
char b[N];
int counter = 0;

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// Hash table
node *table[N];

// Returns true if word is in dictionary, else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    if( word != NULL){
        return true;
        }// TODO
    return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word){

    // TODO: Improve this hash function
        word2 = 0;
        int x = sizeof word;
        a[0] = '\0';
        b[0] = '\0';
        sprintf(b, "%d", word2);

        for(i=0; i < x; i++){
            sprintf(a, "%d", word[i]);
            strcat(b, a);
        }
        word2 = atoi(b);
        return word2;
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // open dict file and check if successful
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if(file == NULL){
    return false;
    }

    //take words from file.
    char word[LENGTH+1];
    while(fscanf(file, "%s", word) != EOF){


        //make new temporary node to store data for words
        node *temp_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if(temp_node == NULL){
            return false;
        }
        //transfer word into temporary node
        memset(temp_node->word, '\0', sizeof(temp_node->word));
        strcpy(temp_node->word, word);
        //set pointer to next node to NULL to prepare for future steps
        temp_node->next = NULL;


        //place temp node into table
        location = hash(temp_node->word);
        if(table[location] == NULL){
            table[location] = temp_node;
            counter = counter + 1;
        }
        else{
            table[location]->next = temp_node;
        }
        fclose(file);
    }
        return true;

}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded, else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    // TODO
    if(counter>0){
        return counter;
    }
    else{
    return 0;
    }
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool unload(void)
{
    // TODO
    node *locat;
    node *ptr;

    for(location = 0; location<=N; location++){
       while(table[location] != NULL){
           ptr = table[location]->next;
           locat = table[location];
           free(locat);
           locat = ptr;
       }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Apologies for the poor readability, and my inability to provide a minimum readable example; It would take me hours and hours to take the code apart and replicate the issue in a smaller algorithm.
I only wrote my first line of code two weeks ago so I have tried my best to make this as easy to understand as possible, but I still need to develop that skill a lot.

Edit:
Regarding multiple words hashing to the same location, I tried to make a hash function where that is impossible so I always have big O(1) as speed is the goal for this problem set. But when I looked, I did notice that it will loop forever so I changed that to a 'while' function instead. Hopefully that's what you are talking about. As far as the fclose(file) issue goes, I have moved that beneath the closing bracket for the loop, and now it is before 'return' in the load function. I still get the same issue though :/

Edit2: dictionary.h contains a definition and a few prototypes, perhaps they could be moved into the dictionary.c file but the rules of the problem set state that I am only allowed to edit the dictionary.c file, and it is called upon in the main algorithm that runs my code.

Edit3: "Do you think that int x = sizeof word; in function hash is somehow related to the length of the string/word or the size of the array in a structure of type node?"
Perhaps. I think that was my intention, though I think 'word' is just a string, rather than a node, being pulled from the .txt file being loaded, but I'm struggling to understand how, exactly, each word is accessed from the text file. In the bool load function it is being referenced as "char word[LENGTH+1];" in all of the tutorials I have watched. Is my issue, perhaps, with the fact that word is defined as a pointer in the hash function, but not in the bool load function?

Edit4: I took `int x = sizeof word;` and removed 'int' so its no longer a declaration, moved it into the load function rather than the hash function, and it seems to be working after the other fixes were made. Now I am getting an issue that seems to be with my freeing the memory space, so I will play with that and if solving that doesn't bring me back to the initial issue, which this post is about, I will mark this solved. Thanks for the help, and thanks for the patience :)

Final edit: It seems the answers provided solved the issue. Now I just need to figure out everything else wrong with my code! Much appreciated!

Comment: What is (in) `"dictionary.h"`?

Comment: Anyway, I don't see what would limit the output of `hash()` to be between 0 and N - 1, so those `table[location]` expressions are a bit suspect.

Comment: Unrelated, your load function is broken. It will leak memory like a sieve when more than two words hash to the same table location. And the `memset` in the function is completely pointless. I'd also get rid of almost all of those global variables. Severely related to your problem, you're closing your file in the while-loop. `fclose(file);` should be moved *outside* (after) the while-loop in your load function.

Comment: Dictionary.h is just a file that contains a list of words to be compared against. The words in there are limited to be, at most, 45 chars long (thats from the file where 'length' is defined). I figure that multiplying length by 26(multiplied by 4 for the four digits possible in its ascii value) would give me a location for every possibility of every word under 45 chars long.

Comment: Do you think that `int x = sizeof word;` in function `hash` is somehow related to the length of the string/word or the size of the array in a structure of type `node`? It is the size of a pointer to a `const char` which might be 8 or 4 on popular platforms.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide requested information, don't use comments for this purpose. If `dictionary.h` is required to compile your program, please provide an example. Otherwise remove the `#include "dictionary.h"` from the source code.